# Find the parametric representation of a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $(u,v)=(x-y,-x-y+{\pi \over 2}$) be a function from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ (the graph of this function is a plane in $\mathbb R^4$) and it passes through the point $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4},0,0)$; Is there a way to find the parametric representation of this plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure. One parametrization is the obvious one: ${\bf x}(x,y) = (x,y,x-y,-x-y+\frac{\pi}{2})$. If $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are the cartesian coordinates in $\Bbb R^4$ you have: $$\Pi: \begin{cases} x_1 = x \\ x_2 = y \\ x_3 = x-y \\ x_4 = -x-y + \frac{\pi}{2}\end{cases}, \quad x,y \in \Bbb R.$$